# How to deal with tiles overlaying with filters?

Tags: flutter

Could someone help me with deal with tiles overlaying with flutter To merge photos on Google Maps?

Comment: https://flutterawesome.com/use-tile-overlay-and-put-custom-image-on-your-map/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.